# Django path to uploaded image

Tags: python, django, image, path, upload

Learning Django, I wanted to build a site where people can upload pictures. The whole account application ( create account, change passward etc. ) is completed, now I have to create a aplication that allows the user to upload images.
I am now finding myself writing the final template, but I don't know how to specify the path the the saved picture.

I have created an Image model that saves the image file offered by the user to the /media/images directory like so : `image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')` .

The form that the user has to complete is :

```
class ImagePost(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image','description','title')
```

So, he has to provide the image, a description and the title (description and title are 2 other attributes of the class Image model.

Here is the view that handles the logic part :

```
@login_required
def image_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # form is sent
        form = ImagePost(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # form data is valid
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            new_item = cd.save(commit=False)
            # assign current user to the item
            new_item.user = request.user
            new_item.save()
            # redirect to new created item detail view
            return render(request,
                      'images/all_images.html',
                      {'new_item': new_item})
    else:
    # build form with data provided by the bookmarklet via GET
        form = ImagePost(data=request.GET)
    return render(request,
                'images/image/create.html',
                {'section': 'images',
                'form': form,
                 })
```

Finally the template that handles the form, currently looks like this :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Post an image{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Post an image</h1>

    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Post it!">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

As the user uploads the picture, the name of the file that now is in my media/images directory has the same name that it had on the user's PC.

How can I find out that name so I can specify Django what file to display? Or is there a way to rename the file so it matches with the title introduced by the user ?

```
<img src="media/images/WHAT_IS_YOUR_NAME" class="image-preview">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `<img src="{{ image.image.url }}" class="image-preview">`

Where `image` is an instance of your `Image` model, the second `image` is the `Image`'s model field and `url` is an attribute of the `ImageField` object. More on it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage), list item #3.

Comment: Should't there be something more like : `<img src="{{ new_item.image.url }}" class="image-preview">` (?) , as when the user submits the form a new instance of the Image model is created with the information and the file provided by the user . Or maybe `<img src="{{ new_item.image.image.url }}" class="image-preview"> `?

Comment: The first one should do the trick! Check it. You do not provide code from your models!!

Comment: It worked ! Sorry for the big delay. I seemed to have a lot of errors overall in my application's code and could not get the server running to test it. Thanks !

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!